# CSS Browser Specific Margins

Tags: css, drupal, webkit, margin, mozilla

I’ve been pulling my hair out about trying to get a couple of elements to line up across browsers. I am working in Drupal 7, if that matters.

I am working on a local vbox vagrant machine, so I cannot link to the content. It also will not let me post a picture, so here are links to the two variations of what is being displayed:

[image]
[image]

The globe and social icons are fonts from Glyphicons and the ssrn icon is a png that I created to mimic them. My problem is they are not responding to margins the same way. I think it has something to do with having to give the glyphicons a negative top margin to line them up, but that leaves the ssrn icon out of line in some browsers. Is there a way to define margins based on webkit etc? I cannot find one.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-website">        <div class="field-content"><div id="website">
<a href="test" title="test" target="_blank" class="glyphicons global"></a>
</div></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-ssrn">        <div class="field-content"><a href="http://test" title="test" target="_blank">
<div id="ssrn"></div>
</a></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-linked-in">        <div class="field-content"><div class="bio-social">
<a href="test" class="social linked_in" title="test" target="_blank"></a>
<div></div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-twitter">        <div class="field-content"><div class="bio-social">
<a href="test" class="social twitter" title="test" target="_blank"></a>
<div></div>  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#website {float: left; width: 24px; margin: 5px 10px 5px 0; width: 48px; height: 48px;}
#website a::before {color: #00479A; font-size: 48px; margin-top: -14px;}
#website a:hover:before {color: #444444;}

#ssrn {height: 48px; width: 48px; float: left; 
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px; /* FIX CROSS BROWSER MARGIN ISSUE!!!!!! */
background-image:url('/sites/all/themes/seeblue_law_subtheme/icons/ssrn1.png'); background-size: 48px;}
#ssrn:hover {background-image:url('/sites/all/themes/seeblue_law_subtheme/icons/ssrn2.png');}

.bio-social {float: left; margin: 5px 10px 5px 0; height: 48px; width: 48px;}
.bio-social a::before {color: #00479A; font-size: 48px; margin-top: -13px;}
.bio-social a:hover:before {color: #444444;}
```

Comment: Please try to make your code readable

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0):

The following properties will not work in every scenario, but are included with Webkit.

```
-webkit-margin-before:
-webkit-margin-end:
-webkit-margin-after:
-webkit-margin-start:

-webkit-padding-before:
-webkit-padding-end:
-webkit-padding-after:
-webkit-padding-start:
```

You can look on [this](http://cssmojo.com/base-styles-sheet-for-webkit-based-browsers/) page for more information.

Also, are you resetting your CSS before you begin testing?

Comment: Yes, the css is reset. I found the easiest way to resolve this was to create a custom font so all elements were the same. Tutorial on creating the font here:

http://rileymacdonald.ca/2013/10/10/how-to-create-custom-glyphicon-fonts/

I just tried to answer my own question, but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://browserclass.org/ which is a standalone JavaScript library. It will add extra classes to your body tag with the current name and version of the browser and with the used OS too, so you will be able to write specific css to handle the problem. This lib also has a Drupal module.

For example you can declare this in your css:

```
  .ff.ff28.mac  .bio-social { ... }
```